# C++ nested loop, increasing base by power

Tags: c++, nested-loops, long-integer

I need some help. I want to achieve a result as shown on my image [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0BWX.jpg)

first question... did my teacher make a mistake? 2^10 = 1024 and not 2048... ?! but nvm..

my only problem is the cout of numbers over 100.000 - please help

here's my code so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <ostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int p;      // exponent
    float b;    // base

    cout << setw(4);
    for (b=1; b<11; b++) {
        cout << " | " << setw(12) << b;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (b=1; b<=10; b++) {
        cout << b;  
        for (p=1; p<=10; p++) {
            cout << " | " << setw(12) << pow(b, p);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output of this is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkgCW.png)

pls pls help,

best regards!

Comment: oh and... can any1 tell me wich of the includes I did I dont need for this? I just added some from tutorials I watched.... as I said, I'm new to C++, normally I'm a Webdesigner - so not much programming :/

Comment: @Rellston There is nothing wrong with the numbers.  They are written in scientific notation.  Is that the issue?

Comment: The second line of the first table seems to be wrong (assuming you want row^col), because 2^3=8 and not 16 (so in fact the rest of that row should shift to the right, and thus ending with 2^10=1024).

Comment: thanks for the super fast replies! whats wrong with my numbers? in my Output Image you can see that 10^10 = 1e+010 and not what I expected it to be: 10000000000!

Comment: @Rellston you do know that 1e+010 **is** 10000000000, right?  It is the formatting, not the result that is wrong.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie no I did not know :O how to change the format?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie and thanks btw! :O

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is output, then the easiest thing to do is cast the `pow()` return value to a `long long` or whatever your compiler's 64-bit `int` type is.

This will automatically use the `long long` overload for `operator <<`, which will effectively remove the scientific notation.

```
 for (p=1; p<=10; p++) {
    cout << " | " << static_cast<long long>(pow(b, p));
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/HuNo5E)

Comment: yes, only the output was the issue :D thank you so much - works perfectly now!!! @PaulMcKenzie